# Script that prints the index and value of unlimited arguments

Tags: python, list, indexing, arguments, sys

I'm learning python and I was wondering if there was a way to input in a lot of arguments and index and print the value of each. All the examples I have looked at so far have argument limitations, but I found that when I use:

```
import sys
print("The arguments are:", str(sys.argv))
```

It will print the values no matter how many arguments I enter.
My question is, is there a way to print the index and values of all these arguments?

Comment: `sys.argv` is just a [**`list`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). You can do whatever you'd normally do with a list. [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) might be useful.

Comment: `sys.argv` may have limit because system may  have limit - and this limit may have all programs which use arguments from command line. (created in all languages). If you need more aguments then write them in file and read them from file in script. Eventually use `input()` or `sys.stdin` to read values from standard input and then you can `pipe` output from one program to input in your script - `other_program | your_script`